# Return AlternativeText from form control button

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to get the alternative text from a form control button?

The following works for shapes:

```
Debug.Print Activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).AlternativeText
```

However, for a button, this does not work:

```
Debug.Print Activesheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).AlternativeText
```

Is it possible to return this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).ShapeRange.AlternativeText
```

The `Button` object doesn't have an `AlternativeText` property, but it does have a `ShapeRange` and `AlternativeText` belongs to the `ShapeRange`.

In the future, assign to an object variable and use the `Locals` window to examine the object's properties at run-time while debugging. Often you can poke around the properties & find what you need!

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, David - Thank you!  Thanks for the screenshot too,  I'm entirely self taught through trial and error and didn't know that the locals would show me all that!  Feels like I have been spelunking in the dark for years and you just handed me a flashlight!

Comment: @rb86 the Locals window is a game-changer. Have a peek at Chip Pearson's brief tutorial on debugging for VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx